# Use Javascript to connect to local SQL Server 2005 express Database

Tags: javascript, database, string, connection, sql-server-2005-express

I am creating a local html application (that will not be used over the internet) on my home computer. I have setup a SQL Server 2005 Express database and am having the hardest time finding a connection string that works. I've tried all the suggestions at http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2005/ and a plethora of other sites including this one, all to no avail.

Each connection type gives me a different error, mostly "SQL Server does not exist or access denied.".

Any help (and guidance) would be much appreciated.

TIA

Comment: AFAIK there is no way to directly connect to SQL Server using Javascript in a browser.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. What options would I have then?

Comment: You could use IndexedDB which is supported in most browsers (except Safari/IOS). It doesn't have all the features that SQL Server has but it's good enough to start with. Just don't try to store 1 million rows on it. 
http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/

Comment: Thank you, but I meant what options do I have to connect to SQL Server 2005 Express. There's got to be a way to do it. I can do it just fine with VWD Express 2010. I just don't want to use VWDe.

Comment: Looks like this one worked. The key was getting my server name correct. I verified by checking my ODBC and looking under where I had chosen "server". Previously, I had been inputting MSSQLServer, which I got from the Services.

connectionstring="Data Source=HOME-MAIN;Initial Catalog=Budget;User ID=sa;Password=*******;Provider=SQLOLEDB";

Thank you for your help. One follow-up. I know this wouldn't be recommended because I expose my database and password and such. If I'm only using this application offline and at home, should I still worry about such security holes?

Comment: I think you are not using javascript to connect to your db.